# What should i store in the user data in the application and how?

Tags: android, firebase, caching, firebase-realtime-database

There is the performance issue when i request the Firebase again and again.grid view update very slowly. so what should i do in this case i am thinking to store the path of the posts in the database. is this good idea or to store in the internal storage.(Caching)

```
private void setuptempGrid(View view){
    setupImageGrid(ProfileActivity.images,view);
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(getString(R.string.db_user_posts))
            .child(application.getUser().getUserId()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot d:dataSnapshot.getChildren() ) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                        .child(getString(R.string.db_posts)).child(getString(R.string.db_public))
                        .child(d.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        gridImageAdapter.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Posts.class).getProfilePic());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

I have this code this take to much time to get the images and every time it loads when my fragment is created.

Comment: use RecyclerView & use AsyncTask maybe

Comment: but i dont want to send the request to the server again and again

Comment: then you can use DBs like Realm or SQLite :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Acc. to [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)

> By enabling persistence, any data that the Firebase Realtime Database client would sync while online persists to disk and is available offline, even when the user or operating system restarts the app. This means your app works as it would online by using the local data stored in the cache.

and also do -

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        .child(getString(R.string.db_user_posts))
        .child(application.getUser().getUserId());
db.keepSynced(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Guava caches as they are optimized and also easy to implement. And before hitting firebase check if you have the data required for the specified node or not.

Comment: but this is on memory caching which can lead to the OOM.

Comment: No it wont. Guava uses many constraints like maximum size of cache, time to cache and so on..